# GNURadio Sending Short Packets

Tags: gnuradio, gmsk

I'm trying to create a basic GNURadio flow graph that will transmit a short message in order to receive an appropriate reply back.

I currently have the following flowgraph:

[image]

I have a program that sends UDP messages to the UDP Source and receives the UDP messages from the UDP Sink

I am able to receive a message from the UDP Sink only if I loop the message I send from the program a couple of times (about 250 at least). Because of this I receive multiple repeated messages, and I wish to receive just one. One way of solving this is through programming, but it is proving to be quite challenging (but should be possible).
Is there a proper way through altering the flow graph parameters with which we can transmit a message without looping or repeating?

Comment: You'll probably have better success by posting your question to the GNU Radio mailing list.